# Wirecard Paymeny Page Easypay2 API integration - TRANSACTION FAILED: Configuration Error. #9700

Tags: api, payment-gateway

I am trying integrate  Wirecard Payment Page Easypay2 API in my website, but i am getting following error from Wirecard.

[image]

Right now i am trying implement in Wirecard test account. I am sending request in following format

```
https://test.wirecard.com.sg/easypay2/paymentpage.do?mid=xxxxxxxxxxx&ref=test-20090928-110&amt=1&cur=SGD&rcard=64&returnurl=http://www.mywebsite.com.sg/wirecard_success.php&statusurl=http://www.mywebsite.com.sg/wirecard_failed.php&paytype=2&transtype=auth&ccnum=4111111111111111&ccdate=1511&cccvv=989&validity=2014-07-29-11:22:33&version=2&signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I am generating this signature in following format.

SHA-512(mid+paytype+ref+amt+cur+security_key)